# Why do I get this unicode warning in one case but not another?

Tags: python, unicode

Using python 2.7 here...

I am encoding/decoding  a string (actually a single character), but I receive a warning :

```
enc.py:22: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

when evaluating the line that reads:  "if (b == c)".  Here is the python code and my output.  I would think that if I get this warning for the "if (b == c)" compare that I would also receive it for the "if (a == c)" comparison, but I don't.  Why?

```
a = "A"
b = a.encode("utf16")
c = b.decode("utf16")

print "Unencoded len(a) = " + str(len(a))
print "utf16 encoded len(a) = " + str(len(b))
print "decoded utf16 length = " + str(len(c))

print ""
print "type(a) = " + str(type(a))
print "type(b) = " + str(type(b))
print "type(c) = " + str(type(c))
print ""

if (b == a):
    print " a = b"
else:
    print " a != b"

if (b == c):
    print " b = c"
else:
    print " b != c"

if (a == c):
    print " a = c"
else:
    print " a != c"
```

Here is my output:

```
Unencoded len(a) = 1
utf16 encoded len(a) = 4
decoded utf16 length = 1

type(a) = <type 'str'>
type(b) = <type 'str'>
type(c) = <type 'unicode'>

 a != b
enc.py:22: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if (b == c):
 b != c
 a = c
```

Comment: It's strange to start with a byte string, and then to encode it. Byte strings are supposed to be already encoded, Unicode strings need encoding when you want to turn them into bytestring. Python 2 allowed this for some reason, 3 doesn't.

Comment: Python 2 allows it because ASCII-only strings are assumed to contain text in the ASCII encoding. Encoding `a` will fail if it contains an accented character like `"Á"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't seen it, this is a really fantastic talk/tutorial on Unicode in Python:

http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Python 2 does some magic behind the scenes and will try to auto-convert unicode/ascii back and forth. I believe that .encode() makes a bytestring, and .decode() converts it back to utf8/ascii.

So b is of type string, but it's an encoded string. What I *believe* is happening (somebody please correct me if I'm wrong, Unicode makes my head hurt) is this:

a = ascii

b = bytestring version of a

c = unicode version of a

Python thinks a and b (and b and c) are different, but then is auto-converting c back to ascii (or a to unicode) and thinks they match.

I bet you Python 3 would complain about a == c, since it tracks the distinction much more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is most likely because when it is converting c before it compares a to c.  I see this as expected behaviour.  It says it right there in the warning that there is an attempted convert.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are not actually comparing two unicode objects, but string object to a unicode object.

try:

```
print type(a), type(b), type(c)
```

and you will see the result:

```
<type 'str'> <type 'str'> <type 'unicode'>
```

the solution is to convert what you want to compare to be the same type ( check [unicode](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for more details).

hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

**In brief:** When you create `b` by encoding `a` into utf-16, you're creating a non-ascii string. Python doesn't keep track of where its contents came from, so when it later needs to convert `b` to unicode, it doesn't know how its contents should be interpreted.

**The details**

Python has two ways of storing text: As unicode characters, whose properties are known and understood by python, or as a sequence of bytes. The latter describes the type `str` in python 2, which in python 3 was renamed to the more appropriate `bytes` (and unicode became the default format for text strings).

Your first conversion, `b = a.encode("utf16")`, succeeds because when python 2 finds bytes in a string that look like ASCII text (characters with ordinal value below 255), it assumes that they *are* ascii text.

As far as python is concerned, **`b` is not unicode text.** It contains a 4-byte sequence representing a utf16-encoded character, but **python doesn't track where byte sequences came from.** So when you trigger automatic conversion to unicode by comparing `b` to a unicode string, python notices that it's not pure ASCII but doesn't know which encoding to use.

Of course, you can convert `b` to unicode by explicitly identifying the encoding, as you did to create `c`:

```
c = b.decode("utf16")
```